# Swift Casting to a protocol returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, prototype, protocols, typecasting-operator

I have array of some values which are of one protocol type. I need to cast those values to another protocol type so that I can access the method from it. But casting is returning nil for me. Why?
What are the conditions to cast from one protocol type to another Protocol type?

```
Protocol Source: CustomStringConvertible, InputDescribeable {
 func getAnimals() -> [Source]}

Protocol Map {
func MapTOAnimal() -> ProtocolX
}

Class Test {
let try = dog.getAnimals() // I have 4 values here of type [Source]
let trytry = try as? Map // returns nil
let needed = trytry.MapToAnimal
}
```

Comment: provide your code with casting method

Comment: "What are the conditions to cast from one protocol type to another Protocol type?" - the object must conform to both protocols

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday or something but with some code? Why didn't you respond to the comments in that question instead of deleting it?

Comment: Type casting doesn't turn an object of one type into another type, it simply tells the compiler how you want to treat a given object at a particular time. `dog.getAnimals()` doesn't actually return an array of `Source`, it returns an array of some class or struct that conforms to the `Source` protocol. In order to cast one of those things to a `Map` the class or struct must conform to `Map` as well as `Source`

Comment: That code is not even valid `swift`, most of keywords are misused: `Protocol` and `Class` should be all-lowercase, `try` is keyword, and shouldn't be used as variable name like that.

Comment: @Paulw11 That means protocol Source and Map should conform to the same class? May be where getAnimals () method is defined?

Comment: No, it means that the concrete class or struct that conforms to `Source` also needs to conform to `Map`. Protocols are abstract. You cannot create an instance of a protocol

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you, It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, you can cast to another protocol that the first protocol extends or if both implement the same protocol. Consider the following example

```
protocol A: CustomStringConvertible {
    func doA() -> Void
}

protocol B: A {
    func doB() -> Void
}

protocol C: CustomStringConvertible {
    func doC() -> Void
}


let arrB = [B]()

let arrA = arrB as! [A]

let arrC = [C]()

let arrD = arrC as! [A]

for  b in arrB {
    b.doB()
    b.doA()
}

for a in arrA {
    a.doA()
    //a.doB()  compilaion error
}

for c in arrC {
    c.doC()
    let descr = c.description
}

for d in arrD {
    // d.doC() compilaion error
    let descr = d.description
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try above code. But force casting is not allowed in our project.

Comment: It’s just a simple example thus the forced casting instead of a more proper implementation